# NDCG-score in top-k recommendations

Tags: greatest-n-per-group, ranking, recommendation-engine, evaluation, ranking-functions

Rating prediction taks in Recommender Systems.
I have prepared a custom data set, and I applied models to predict rating which user gave to the item.
I keep getting the results, where NDCG-5 is higher than NDCG-3.
Is it really possible?
Attached, I send file with the results per user.

I tried two libraries to calclulate NDCG with python:

1. sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score
2. tfr.keras.metrics.NDCGMetric

I expected that NDCG-5 will be lower. Instead, it is higher!

Comment: It depends on your data set. There's no reason why one would be consistently higher/lower than the other.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the NDCG for top-5 can be (indeed) be higher than NDCG for top-3.
Some models provide a higher ranking for top-3, but lower for top-5.
The example is shown below in the code:

[image]